# Sharing/Extending a DbContext from an MVC .NET Core application to a (Razor) class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, class-library

I have a web application with its own dbcontext (context1), and I've a Razor class library with another dbcontext (context2). Ideally I should have a single db context...

The problem i have is when some tables "overlap", e.g. context1 contains entity companies, and context2 contains entity users, yet there mayb be a relationship between companies and users.

- Is there a way i can ditch context2 from my CL and somehow inject context1 into my class library?
- Or perhaps there is a way i can inherit context2 to context1?
- Alternatively, if i keep the two contexts, can i keep the from "overlapping", e.g create a view to allow navigation properites between the two contexts? (just thinking out loud now)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have one context definition or two isn't really the issue, it will be how any instance of a DbContext is scoped and whether a single reference can be shared across the two blocks of code.

For instance if I have some code in an MVC project that is doing something like:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
     var myEntity = context.Entities.Single(x => x.EntityId = entityId);
     SomeService.DoSomething(myEntity);
}
```

and a service library doing something like:

```
public void DoSomething(AppEntity someEntity)
{
    using(var context = new AppContext())
    {
        someEntity.Status = "DidSomething";
        context.Attach(someEntity);
        context.Entity(someEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

or the like, then you're probably shaping up for a world of discomfort tracking down stale state related issues. Both blocks of code can be referring to the same DbContext *type* but different DbContext *instances* which means that the controller's DbContext reference may not reflect, or be tracking entities that the other library context had committed.

As a general rule, an entity should not leave the scope of the DbContext instance that spawned it. Any entity that does should be considered detached, but if it is not explicitly detached from a DbContext instance, this can lead to errors down the road depending on how long-lived the DbContext that spawned it is. If one assembly references the second assembly then you can use Dependency Injection and an IoC container to manage a lifetime scope of a single DbContext instance across calls, or you can use a Unit of Work provider to provision a DbContext and manage the lifetime of that DbContext.  This way, when your library is referenced by MVC, it shares a DbContext instance when called, but if called via another means, it resolves a suitable DbContext instance for entities received from that scenario.

For larger systems it can be prudent to use separate DbContext definitions and simplified entity definitions. Smaller, simpler, short-lived DbContexts operate more efficiently when querying/tracking entities. For services that may get called frequently to operate against data, it can be far better to have a simplified entity against a smaller DbContext. Fetch the entity, inspect, modify, and commit rather than trying to attach, modify, and commit using a full-size entity on a full size DbContext instance. Models like this would use minimum-sized payloads (DTOs) rather than entities as payloads. Callers would receive an indication that their scoped entities should be refreshed or not.